Why global-scope function declaration with built-in type arg must be visible before unqualified call to that name with argument of template type?
tl;dr
Given the definition of Foo below, why a call to
Foo{2}();

is possible only if draw(int); is declared before Foo definition?
Non-language-lawyer answer
Ok, apparently a very similar example is shown in C++ Templates - The Complete Guide in §14.3.2, and the reason is roughly that when a tempalate is first seen, any unqualified dependent name (e.g. the draw in operator() below, which is dependent because t is of type the template parameter T) is looked up. In my example, at that point, draw(int) is not visible yet. Later, when the call Foo{2}(); is parsed, only ADL is peformed, and so draw(int) is not found because the set of namespaces associated to int is empty.
But how do I understand this from the standard? I suppose the answer is in [basic.lookup], but can anybody guide me to decypher it?
Longer version
Consider

these headers:

one exposes a class template with a call operator (or other member function, fwiw) calling an unqualified draw function on an object of the template type,
// foo.hpp
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T t;
    void operator()() {
        draw(t);
    }
};


one exposes a namespaced class, with associated draw function,
// bar.hpp
namespace bar {
struct Bar {};
void draw(Bar const&);
}


one exposes a global-scope draw for ints,
// drawInt.hpp
void draw(int);




the corresponding cpp files:
// the cpp files
void draw(int) {
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}
namespace bar {
void draw(Bar const&){
    std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
}
}


and the main,
// main.cpp
#include "drawInt.hpp"
#include "bar.hpp"
#include "foo.hpp"
int main() {
    Foo{bar::Bar{}}();
    Foo{2}();
}



Compiling and executing with
g++ -std=c++20 *.cpp -O0 -o main && ./main

is successful and prints
Bar
int

the call to void bar::draw(bar::Bar) is possible because of ADL, and we don't even really need bar::Bar and bar::draw be declared in any way before Foo for the code to work, i.e. changing
#include "bar.hpp"
#include "foo.hpp"

to
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "bar.hpp"

has no effect on the program (I get the same exact binary). After all, the inside of operator() can't be even be meaningfully looked at by the compiler, before the line
Foo{bar::Bar{}}();

triggers template type deduction of T.
On the other hand, the call to void draw(int) that corresponds to
Foo{2}();

is not resolved via ADL.
But why does that imply that the declaration of that overload of draw must be visible before the definition of Foo, which in turns means that the order of #includes in main becomes important?
I mean, by the time
Foo{2}();

is seen, void draw(int) is visible.
And, whatever the reason is, is that a symptom of bad design?
But then what's the benefit of ADL, if I can't use it seamlessly together non-ADL calls for builtin types? In this respect, I'm thinking about Sean Parent runtime concept idiom (the ADL call is 35:57 of Better Code: Runtime Polymorphism - Sean Parent.

There's not much more to it than what you already see. Unqualified calls in templates require either ADL, or a definition visible at the time of template declaration.

In general, you're supposed to make ADL functions only for the parameter types you own, or if you own the caller. The file with draw(int) seems to be neither.

@HolyBlackCat, I get that, and now I've also found a reference to it in C++ Templates from Josuttis, but I'd like to learn how to read/deduced it from standard.

You've pointed at the section in the standard of relevance. Unqualified name lookup finds preceding declarations. Then argument dependent lookup applies. Name lookup is a large subject. Is there a particular statement that's unclear?

The "what is the benefit" doesn't seem to fit well with the rest, that's rarely a language lawyer thing with a standard reference. But the point is that it is a means of customization. Whoever provides the draw interface will implement it for the fundamental types and/or library types that they own or that it makes sense. Meanwhile the user implements it for their own types which the draw provider cannot know about.

And how to dispatch between ADL implementations and the provided ones is a large topic but you've hinted at one way. The header that defines Foo, which calls draw, can include the header that provides draw (for non-ADL cases). Either way, the tradeoffs in the choices here are really their own question.

@JeffGarrett, what I meant by "what's the benefit" is that draw(b) looks the same whether b is a ::bar::Bar and draw is a ::bar::draw or b is a int and draw is a ::draw. So having the two behave differently in the two cases... doesn't seem the most intuitive thing to me. I didn't know that built-in types and user-defined types were so different.

@JeffGarrett, as regards "can include the header", yes it can, but should it? foo.hpp could be owned by a team (which could also define some type which implements draw, in which case it would make sense for foo.hpp to #include that header), and other teams could be defining their own types with the associated implementation of the draw interface. The owners of foo.hpp shouldn't include those headers because in principle they don't even know they exist (and most importantly they #include "foo.hpp"). It's the "main" TU that #include "foo.hpp" and links against implementers.

The team that owns the draw interface is the one that also implements it for fundamental or standard types. Since Foo is using that interface, it includes that header. Other teams' types that implement draw implement it in the same header with their type. foo.hpp shouldn't include those headers and need not.

So my answer to: given foo.hpp uses draw(), should it include the main header for draw, which might include associated concepts, the types required for the signature, and includes any built-in or default implementations is yes.

draw(t) is a dependent call ([temp.dep.general]/2), which makes the function name a dependent name in this context. As specified in [basic.lookup.argdep]/4, when argument-dependent lookup is performed for a dependent name, it searches both in the definition context and the instantiation context. Thus, as long as the appropriate draw overload is declared before the point of instantiation, it can be found by ADL.
However, ADL only looks in associated namespaces; it doesn't duplicate the behaviour of ordinary unqualified name lookup. Because int is a fundamental type, it has no associated namespaces, so when the argument to a dependent call has type int, there is nothing for ADL to look in, and nothing is found. In order for draw(t) to compile when t is of type int, draw must be found by ordinary unqualified name lookup, which will only find names that are visible from the definition context ([temp.res.general]/1).
